# tinymce into jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, tinymce, jqgrid-asp.net

I work with ASP.Net MVC 4.
How can I insert tinymce into jqgrid?
When I add a new record I want to show the TinyMCE editor; what "wysiwyg" editor is more compatible with jqgrid?

Regards 
Ricardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need is for jqgrid to be able to set your own custom class or ID on the textarea or div that you need to edit with TinyMCE. And also the init code for tinyMCE set to that same class-name as in this example:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

In that configuration, tinyMCE is set to load on all textareas, but you can change that to any CSS-selector, such as '.myClassName' or '#myTextarea'.